# 'Link' is only available in macOS 11.0 or newer

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a text link that opens a web page externally with safari from my macOS app written with SwiftUI.

```
var body: some View {          
   Link("Visit Apple", destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!) 
}
```

This only works if my deployment target is for macOS 11.0 and above but i want it to work for 10.15 which shows these errors:

```
'Link' is only available in macOS 11.0 or newer 
 
'init(_:destination:)' is only available in macOS 11.0 or newer
```

Is there an alternative way to open external links for 10.15?

Comment: 'Link' is only available in macOS 11.0 or newer.

Comment: is there an alternative way to open external links for 10.15?

Comment: Yeah, just use a Button and call ‘UIApplication.openURL(your irl here)’ (on phone rn, code might not be exact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`open(_:options:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open).

Try the following:

```
var body: some View {
    Button("Visit Apple") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
    }
}
```

To open the URL on macOS:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
```

Comment: Thanks! the macOS version is  'NSWorkspace.shared.open'

Comment: @swiftnoob Just found the exact same thing! Will update answer now